# PHP SoapClient unable to access webservice using proxy

Tags: php, proxy, soap-client

Using SoapClient in PHP, I've come across a problem I have not been able to find a solution to.

I'm using a local copy of the wsdl file and I am using this setup:

```
$this->client = new \SoapClient(__DIR__ . '/../../some.wsdl',
                        array(
                                'proxy_host'    => $ip,
                                'proxy_port'    => $port,
                                'trace' => 1,
                                'exceptions' => true,
                                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                        )
                    );
```

This gives error : "Forbidden"  when calling :

```
$this->client->__call($method, $params)
```

I have tried calling __getFunctions()

```
$this->client->__getFunctions()
```

that gives the list of all function in my WSDL file.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Debug code with like this :

```
<?php 
    try{
            $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $params);
            $out = $client;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $out =  array('error' => $e,  'libxml' => libxml_get_last_error());
        }catch(SoapFault $s){
            $out = array('error' => $s, 'libxml' => libxml_get_last_error());
        }
    var_dump($out);
    exit();
```

Comment: I tried this code, it gives : 

object(SoapClient)#1 (5) { ["_proxy_host"]=> string(13) "192.xxx.xxx.x" ["_proxy_port"]=> int(80) ["trace"]=> int(1) ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(4) of type (Unknown) }

Comment: So , add __call method in try { } part and see message

Comment: `array(2) { ["error"]=> object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(9) "Forbidden" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(35) "/home/xxx/www/file.php" ["line":protected]=> int(18) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["function"]=> string(11) "__doRequest" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(276) " 93048 " [1]=> string(57) "http://url/proxy/file.asmx" `

Comment: I think you miss a configuration proxy or permissions access path to file watch on this way

Comment: your're welcome , you can watch php manual too :
http://php.net/manual/fr/class.soapclient.php